# Можно сделать настройки QSettings на 2 и более приложения?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qsettings

Есть 2 приложения: 1- создает где-то файл, а 2- должно пойти по какому-то пути и забрать содержимое файла.

Могу ли я в первом приложении указать путь к файлу в QSettings, а вторым забрать из реестра этот путь и перейти по нему к файлу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можите, конечно. Но более удобным, в этом сцееарии, кажется передача данных через QSharedMemory, а не через файл. Имя файла, в этом случае, ненужно. Есть и другие средства, предназначенные именно для меж-процессного взаимодйствия:

Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html

boost:  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Comment: В QSharedMemory есть серьезный минус, нужно сохранять последовательность запуска приложений.